# I have created an virtual SDCARD from cmd but now i dont know where is it located that sdcard dir?

Tags: android

[image: Hi this is what i have done so far]

now what path should I put on the run configuration from eclpse and where is exactly my virtual sd card if i wanna put some files there how can i put?

Comment: and in Additional Emulator Command i have: -sdcard C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\mysdcard is that correct, if it is then why it is not appearing on the DDMS, File Explorer, there are only three folders data,mtn,system, where is mysdcard here?

Comment: sdcard folder is always mounted in mnt folder
Ex: /mnt/sdcard

Comment: yeah there is an sdcard folder there in mnt, but i have used to create another name of that called mysdcard from cmd, using android SDK/tools, and I am wondering whats the exact location of mysdcard and how to put files there

Comment: I guess that's the one you have mounted. Check if its showing the same capacity sdcard as "mysdcard" which you created in the beginning cos I dont think you can mount more than one sdcard at same time.

Comment: how can i check the capacity of this is which is alredy on amulator, and if suppoze is this one, what shoud it be the Path string when i declare sd card string on my class for ex:private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("C:/android-sdk-windows/tools/mysdcard/"); is this one correct or i have to make it sdcard only at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered quite nicely in this site. Do try out.. :)

[Emulating sdcard](http://www.anddev.org/emulating_a_sd-card-t263.html)

Comment: Same things he has done as I have done, I am only doubting on my Additional Emulator Command i have: -sdcard C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\mysdcard is that correct.

Comment: u need to use .img extension to you filename to make it work properly. In both cases ie while creating as well as in Additional Emulator Command line options to mount it.

Comment: Two common ways to browse your sdcard are:

a. In Eclipse, open DDMS Perspective, and open File Explorer view, you can browse /sdcard directory. In this mode, you can drag and drop files.

b. Using commandline, go to adb shell by typing:

adb -e shell
Then access to /sdcard directory by typing:

# cd /sdcard
You can use push/pull from adb shell to put files into sdcard or get files from it.

Comment: I can see mysdcard file as zip file so means like it is there, but in my DDMS prespective i see only three files data,mnt,system there is no mysdcard file from where i can put the musics. i think i am clear now

Comment: there is no sdcard lol, it is inside mnt an sdcard folder but is that one i created??? I named it as Mysdcard not sdcard only

Comment: "mysdcard" is only the volume name of sdcard u created. And as i said before, try creating an sdcard with proper extension so as to use it like actual sdcard.

Comment: "try creating an sdcard with proper extension so as to use it like actual sdcard" what do you mean by this, where to create it ?

Comment: i think i have screwed up everything, even now that mnt/sdcard i cant push files here it says Failed to push item(s)

Comment: I am lost with this SDCARD, no way i can fix it. i have created the sdcard i can see it in sdk-android-windows/tools but i cant see it on exlipse DDMS prespective

Comment: how can I use the shell to check whethere there is sd card on my emulator?

Comment: -1 Answers that only contain a link elsewhere are [bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @Samuel: I meant to specify the .img extension while creating the virtual sdcard. First try creating as is shown in some working tutorial to find out where you might be getting it wrong( which I think is probably the missing extension in ur case)

Comment: @alextsc : The link I provided solved his problem quite well and besides that I m helping him in his problem. I don't think my answer deserved that downvote. Anyways, won't be arguing over that, its your kind wish.

Comment: @pansp Yes you helped him. SO just isn't about helping just the OP. You also help x search engine users behind the scenes. Nothing more frustrating than finding an answer to your question and it only contains a dead link.